# Limit of infinite sequence from partial sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I think there was a rule in Calculus that mentions this, but I am not sure.

> If I need to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and I am only given the nth partial sum: $S_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k = f(n)$

To find $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ I just have to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ correct?

Comment: Hint:  $a_n=f(n)-f(n-1)$

Comment: @lulu so $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)-f(n-1)$ I have to find?

Comment: Yes. $\quad \quad$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed by lulu in the comment note that

$$S_n-S_{n-1} =\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k = a_n\color{red}{+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k}=a_n=f(n)-f(n-1)$$

---

Remark:

- that is precisely the reason for which $a_n\to 0$ is a necessary condition for the convergence of any series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$, indeed

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k=L \implies S_n-S_{n-1} =a_n \to 0$$

Comment: So the limit of my sequence is always 0!? If partial sums exist?

Comment: @StackUser With reference to the OP we have that $a_n=f(n)-f(n-1)$ therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)-f(n-1)$$

Comment: @StackUser The remark given refers to a more general fact about the series, it is not strictly related to your specific example.

Comment: Omm, I am not sure if I get it but, what is happening is that. We are trying to find the last term of $a_n$ which is equivalent to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$$ and we are doing that by subtracting "the space that is covered" by the partial sums as n goes to infinity to get what the last term will be?

Comment: @StackUser Do not consider the remark to solve the question, it is another fact we can discuss later. For the OP we need to find $a_n$ and we can use the $S_n=S_{n-1}+a_n\implies a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$. Here we are using a finite value for $n$. Once we have $a_n$ we can evaluate the limit.

Comment: Oh i see now. Thank you

Comment: @StackUser You are welcome! Bye